# Magento Upgrade Error

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I am upgrading magento website from **1.6.2 to 1.9.3.1** and  it seemed to have went successfully but website was not properly displayed.

I found this error and I don't know what to do to solve it.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:94:"Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category::shouldDisplayProductCount(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:3719:"#0 /home/mystore/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml(42): Varien_Object->__call('shouldDisplayPr...', Array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that is being reported mentions a method `shouldDisplayProductCount()` in a class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category` which extends from a parent class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract` that actually contains a method with this name. So the error tells that there is something corrupt in your install: If your Magento 1.9 core is giving this error, this either means that there is PHP caching in place that is caching the PHP code, or that the core is not intact. I would recommend you to check with the hosting provider to see whether there is some kind of PHP caching going on (APC, Zend OPCache) and if so, to ask for instructions on how to deal with PHP changes. If it is the core code that indeed gives this issue, make sure to take a fresh Magento 1.9 fileset and copy it over to your current Magento site.

Comment: Thank you. I checked with the hosting provider, my Magento works with PHP 5.4 which does not have any caching enabled within the PHP itself.